# Module installed via "pip install modulename" results in "modulename: command not found"

Tags: command-line, python, pip

I'm running ubuntu *cosmic* and have tried searching for a solution, but all solutions are regarding `pip: command not found`

*pip* seems to work fine (freshly installed via `sudo apt-get install python-pip`). After this I ran `pip install modulename` which also worked fine, but once I try running the module, I receive a command not found.

I did check `echo $PATH` which does not contain the directory the modules are installed to (`~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`), but I have not found a single post that seemed to have the same problem as mine, and I already learned that wildly running commands in the hope to find a solution is more likely to break things.

In case it helps, I'm trying to run *keen* and *keenmqtt*.

I hope somebody is able to help :)
Thanks!

Comment: ahh there's a mistake in my post, i Installed python-pip, not pip. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

solved it by adding `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin` to ~/.bashrc